# Run Velocity code in Liferay Web Content

Tags: liferay, portlet, webcontent

I've a web content and I'd like to import another portlet inside of my web content. Is that possible?

I've tried using the code:

```
#set($TopNaviC = $journalContentUtil.getContent($themeDisplay.getCompanyGroupId(),'11105', null, "$locale",$theme_display)) 
$TopNaviC
```

Yours
Heikki

Comment: It just prints that as a normal characters. Parser won't touch on it.

So it prints: #set........

Answer (score 1):

You can archieve that with:

```
<div id="embedded-welcome-portlet">
  <runtime-portlet name="56" instance="5555" queryString=""/>
</div>
```

...where...

- name = this name belongs to journal content as stated in /WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml
- instance = 4 digit number

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct example

```
#set ($local_temp_content = $journalContentUtil.getContent($scope_group_id, $temp_article_id, null, "$locale", $theme_display))
```

Comment: This works perfectly in the template, but does it work if I put this as the web content?

Comment: This is only for the template. It's non sense talking about this as a webcontent.

Comment: It would give me more user moderable possibilities if there'd be a way.